# Ansible: reduce to the variable from registers of each host

Tags: ansible

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Read the file
    command: cat the_file
    register: the_file

  - name: Reduce them
    set_fact:
      result: "{{ the_file.stdout }}"
      reduce: yes # magic option
```

When the_file in each host written as "a", "b", "c" respectively, is it possible to get the variable like `["a", "b", "c"]` or `"abc"`?

Hosts are not connected by ssh each other, but only from the playbook running one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables from the *hostvars*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'the_file')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
result: [a, b, c]
```

You can *join* the items if you want to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'the_file')|join }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
result: abc
```

See [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) and fit the list of the hosts to your needs.